# JSON not printing to ListView

Tags: android, json, listview, android-listview

This one has been gnawing at me for a while now, I've created a AsyncTask to pull products from my Database and I want them to be displayed in a listView no build errors occure and LogCat prints out the JSON code but nothing is printed to the listview

```
private class LoadJsonTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> > {
    ProgressDialog dialog ;
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(GetProducts.this ,"Loading","Please wait");
    }
    protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground (String... params) {
        return doGetJson();
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
}

public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> doGetJson() {
    JSONObject json = null;

    ArrayList<String> mylist = new ArrayList<String>();
    Functions uf = new Functions();
    json = uf.getProducts();
    try {

        //the array title that you parse
        JSONArray category = json.getJSONArray("products");

        ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i=0; i < category.length() ; i++) {
            JSONObject c = category.getJSONObject(i);
            String name = c.getJSONObject("name").toString();
            String products = c.getJSONObject("price").toString();
            items.add(name);
            items.add(products);
            Log.d(name,"Output");
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> mArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, items);
        ListView ProductList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        mArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        ProductList.setAdapter(mArrayAdapter);

    } catch (JSONException e) { }
    return null;
}
```

The LogCat prints out

```
1-05 23:08:09.732: E/JSON(17841): {"tag":"getProducts","success":1,"error":0,"products":{"name":"Coffee1","price":"4.00","image":"http:\/\/test.com"}}{"tag":"getProducts","success":1,"error":0,"products":{"name":"Coffee2","price":"5.00","image":"http:\/\/test2.com"}}
```

But as I say nothing is printed to my ListView it just remains blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code where you create the `ArrayAdapter` and set it on the `ListView` should be executed on the UI thread (from `onPostExecute`).:

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> mArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, items);
    ListView ProductList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    ProductList.setAdapter(mArrayAdapter);
```

You cannot do this work on a background thread.

You are already returning a HashMap of the information, so you just need to move that code out of `doInBackground` and into `onPostExecute`.

Also you can remove the call to `notifyDataSetChanged` as this is the initial data load. So I would make these changes:

- Your AsyncTask should return the ArrayList: Replace everywhere you have `HashMap<String, String>` with `ArrayList<String>`
- After the for loop in doGetJson, `return items`
- The parameter to onPostExecute is now `ArrayList<String>` (from step 1) so you can now use this parameter to build the adapter.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. When you say "That code" do you mean the for loop or everything after the for loop?

Comment: Hi, when I move it over to onPostExceute it tells me that "Items" cannot be found - does the doInBackground need to be returning items somehow?

Comment: Returning items in doGetJson gives me the error Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList<String> to ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>

Comment: As I mentioned in the answer already. All instances of ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>  should be replaced with ArrayList<String>

Comment: So that's it? Did that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] itemsArray = items.toArray(new String[items.size()]); // convert list to array
ArrayAdapter<String> mArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, itemsArray);
ListView ProductList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
ProductList.setAdapter(mArrayAdapter); // swap the last two lines like this
mArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

im guessing this should fix your problem

updated the code

Comment: That gives me the same issues as above items isn't found and returning it generates the error

Comment: so, is there anything in the items List?

Comment: Yes the for loop in the code above adds things to the item list

Comment: ah, you are using an arrayList instead of an array, afaik the adapter cant handle an arraylist

Comment: When I put your updated code in onPostExecute it says items cannot be resolved

Comment: well, what you need to do is convert your arraylist into an array, my code should do that, cant tell what happened there

Comment: You cannot do this on the background thread. setAdapter and notifyDataSetChanged will both throw exceptions. See my answer.